# How to remove hidden fields in tableau sheet while exporting as cross tab from tableau server?

Tags: csv, crosstab, tableau-api

I am using **Tableau Desktop** & **Server 9.3**. I have created field named as **'Sales'**.
There are many other measures and dimensions have been included in sheet along with field 'Sales'. But for some reasons I've to **hide** **'Sales' field**.
 I've done this by **unchecking**  option **'Show Header'**.
I have published my workbook on tableau server. **I want to download the sheet as cross tab 
(i.e in csv format).**
 When I am trying to do so it is giving me **all fields including 'Sales' field in csv file**.
I **don't want to show 'Sales'** field in **csv**. 
How can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way in Tableau to selectively show fields in the crosstab download.

I think the best approach, currently, is to create a text table with the fields that you want to show and allow the users to download that text table.

You could provide a button to link to this text table from the main dashboard.